# How can I make this Java leap year program loop?

Tags: java

I have to make a program that tells you if a year is a leap year or not, for a class. I have the basic function of the program done, but I want it to be able to ask the user if they want to do the whole thing again (if they enter yes, it would repeat the program. If they enter no, the program would terminate). I would preferably use while loops but I can't quite figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

```
System.out.println("This program will let you enter a year and it will tell you" +
        " if it is a lear year");
int lyear;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a valid gregorian year(greater than 1581): ");
lyear = scan.nextInt();

    boolean LeapYear = ((lyear % 4 == 0) && (lyear % 100 != 0) || (lyear % 400 == 0));

    if (lyear < 1582)
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a gregorian year"); 
    }
    else if (LeapYear)
    {
        System.out.println("That is a leap year"); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a leap year"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function `checkLeapYear()`, and copy your current code into it.

Now write a `while` loop:

```
boolean repeat = true;

while (repeat) {
  checkLeapYear();

  //prompt user to enter yes/no if they want to run again
  String answer = ...

  repeat = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to proceed with the following code snippet -

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
   line = scan.readLine();
   if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"){
    continue;
   }esle{
    try{
       int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){}
   }
}
```